# What is aparigraha vrat?

Tags: sadhana, vrata

- Can anyone start [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aparigraha) practice?
- Is it a lifetime process or can we practice it for few weeks or months like deeksha?
- Does it have any limitations/exceptions?
- To what extent does it permit to depend on others for livelihood?

Answer (score 1):

[aparigraha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aparigraha) (Sanskrit: अपरिग्रह) is the virtue of non-possessiveness, non-grasping or non-greediness,  is a part of [Yamas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yamas).

And, Yama is a part of [Asthanga Yoga](http://www.ashtanga.com/html/background.html).

---

Coming to the questions:

- Is it a lifetime process or can we practice it for few weeks or
  months like deeksha?
- Does it have any limitations/exceptions?
- To  what extent does it permit to depend on others for livelihood?

---

***A word of caution:***

Ashtanga yoga is solely meant ***for serious spiritual practitioners***, but not for people with worldly ambitions.

The first 2 Angas or parts of this method, ie., Yama and Niyama were designed to ***purify oneself inwardly*** and 3rd one i.e, Asana to make fit one physically so that subsequent parts can be achieved easily.

---

1. Practicing ***aparigraha*** should be for life, as  progress in Dharana, Dhyana depends on the success in aparigraha and others in Yama and Niyama.
2. One can earn money, without avarice,  for one's and family's livelihood and to discharge one's responsibilities.